# MessageBox.Show() causes crash in Mono on Mac

Tags: winforms, macos, mono, osx-yosemite

I ported a WinForms application to Mac OS X 10.10.2 using Mono 3.12.1.  The main window comes up fine.  But when I try to show a message box with System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Hello") from a worker thread, the message box will display briefly and then the program crashes with:

mono(20661,0xa0f5e1d4) malloc: *** error for object 0x7a6d86e0: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Stacktrace:

at  <0xffffffff>
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Windows.Forms.XplatUICarbon.ReceiveNextEvent (uint,intptr,double,bool,intptr&) <0xffffffff>
  at System.Windows.Forms.XplatUICarbon.GetMessage (object,System.Windows.Forms.MSG&,intptr,int,int) <0x0007f>
  at System.Windows.Forms.XplatUI.GetMessage (object,System.Windows.Forms.MSG&,intptr,int,int) <0x00039>
  at System.Windows.Forms.Application.RunLoop (bool,System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext) <0x00aff>
  at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run (System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext) <0x0004f>
  at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run (System.Windows.Forms.Form) <0x00033>
  at RevelarPcCommX.Program.Main () <0x0003f>
  at (wrapper runtime-invoke) object.runtime_invoke_void (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) <0xffffffff>

I can execute this message box function from the main window code fine.  But the program crashes when this code is executed from another thread on the Mac.  By the way, the message box displays fine on a worker thread on a Windows 7 PC.  So, I guess the question is, how do I execute this message box on the main thread from a worker thread on the Mac?  Or maybe there is another solution to fix this crash on the Mac?

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess but I had similar issues when I had `CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls` for testing purposes and forgot to remove it. Doing anything like invocations on a different thread would cause crashes, despite it working fine under Windows. So, check for two things:

1. Make sure you're not using `CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls`. It's bad practice anyway.
2. Make sure you are using safe invocations on your worker thread; you might not be doing so if you're just calling `MessageBox.Show`